# Can Application Experience service recyle an AppPool?

Tags: iis, web-server

I'm experiencing the mysterious recycling of an app pool once in a day or two. The event log says "An administrator has requested a recycle of all worker processes in application pool 'API'", but the only person logged in was me, and I'm pretty sure I didn't do it. Every time, just a few seconds before the recycle, the Application Experience service was started. Could it cause the recycling somehow, and how?

Windows Server 2021 R2, IIS 8.5.

Comment: So the pool is recycled every time you log in? Did you configure any login script or startup apps? Since logging in triggers all of them and they run under your account, no wonder event log entry said that.